# parse XML response with namespaces

Tags: php, xml, xpath, namespaces, nodes

I am sending a request to get product info to Amazon and I am getting a response from them that is formatted in XML - it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetMatchingProductForIdResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
  <GetMatchingProductForIdResult Id="3U-R7EP-QODZ" IdType="SellerSKU" status="Success">
    <Products>
      <Product>
        <Identifiers>
          <MarketplaceASIN>
            <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
            <ASIN>B0002DV7Z2</ASIN>
          </MarketplaceASIN>
        </Identifiers>
        <AttributeSets>
          <ns2:ItemAttributes xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd" xml:lang="en-US">
            <ns2:Binding>Electronics</ns2:Binding>
            <ns2:Brand>Pioneer</ns2:Brand>
            <ns2:Color>Black</ns2:Color>
            <ns2:Feature>Whether a DJ, studio musician, sound engineer or just an avid music listener, the HDJ-1000 is the answer to all of your headphone needs.</ns2:Feature>
            <ns2:Feature>Large diameter speaker units.</ns2:Feature>
            <ns2:Feature>Folding housing with universal joints.</ns2:Feature>
            <ns2:Feature>Stereo/Mono selector switch allows mix of left and right channel signals for single ear monitoring.</ns2:Feature>
            <ns2:Feature>Removable 1/4" jack reveals mini plug for flexible connections, includes carrying case.</ns2:Feature>
            <ns2:ItemDimensions>
              <ns2:Height Units="inches">11.50</ns2:Height>
              <ns2:Length Units="inches">13.00</ns2:Length>
              <ns2:Width Units="inches">12.60</ns2:Width>
              <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">0.60</ns2:Weight>
            </ns2:ItemDimensions>
            <ns2:IsAutographed>false</ns2:IsAutographed>
            <ns2:IsMemorabilia>false</ns2:IsMemorabilia>
            <ns2:Label>Pioneer Pro DJ</ns2:Label>
            <ns2:ListPrice>
              <ns2:Amount>200.00</ns2:Amount>
              <ns2:CurrencyCode>USD</ns2:CurrencyCode>
            </ns2:ListPrice>
            <ns2:Manufacturer>Pioneer Pro DJ</ns2:Manufacturer>
            <ns2:Model>HDJ-1000</ns2:Model>
            <ns2:NumberOfItems>1</ns2:NumberOfItems>
            <ns2:PackageDimensions>
              <ns2:Height Units="inches">4.20</ns2:Height>
              <ns2:Length Units="inches">10.00</ns2:Length>
              <ns2:Width Units="inches">9.50</ns2:Width>
              <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">1.30</ns2:Weight>
            </ns2:PackageDimensions>
            <ns2:PackageQuantity>1</ns2:PackageQuantity>
            <ns2:PartNumber>HDJ-1000</ns2:PartNumber>
            <ns2:ProductGroup>Musical Instruments</ns2:ProductGroup>
            <ns2:ProductTypeName>SOUND_AND_RECORDING_EQUIPMENT</ns2:ProductTypeName>
            <ns2:ProductTypeSubcategory>26705100</ns2:ProductTypeSubcategory>
            <ns2:Publisher>Pioneer Pro DJ</ns2:Publisher>
            <ns2:ReleaseDate>2008-12-08</ns2:ReleaseDate>
            <ns2:SmallImage>
              <ns2:URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31I5ac8P-wL._SL75_.jpg</ns2:URL>
              <ns2:Height Units="pixels">75</ns2:Height>
              <ns2:Width Units="pixels">75</ns2:Width>
            </ns2:SmallImage>
            <ns2:Studio>Pioneer Pro DJ</ns2:Studio>
            <ns2:Title>Pioneer HDJ-1000 DJ Headphones</ns2:Title>
            <ns2:Warranty>1 Year Exchange</ns2:Warranty>
          </ns2:ItemAttributes>
        </AttributeSets>
        <Relationships>
          <VariationParent xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
            <Identifiers>
              <MarketplaceASIN>
                <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
                <ASIN>B0074L8U64</ASIN>
              </MarketplaceASIN>
            </Identifiers>
          </VariationParent>
        </Relationships>
        <SalesRankings>
          <SalesRank>
            <ProductCategoryId>musical_instruments_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId>
            <Rank>28094</Rank>
          </SalesRank>
        </SalesRankings>
      </Product>
    </Products>
  </GetMatchingProductForIdResult>
  <GetMatchingProductForIdResult Id="86-CK3P-PHK6" IdType="SellerSKU" status="Success">
    <Products>
      <Product>
        <Identifiers>
          <MarketplaceASIN>
            <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
            <ASIN>0061785679</ASIN>
          </MarketplaceASIN>
        </Identifiers>
        <AttributeSets>
          <ns2:ItemAttributes xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd" xml:lang="en-US">
            <ns2:Author>Rollins, James</ns2:Author>
            <ns2:Binding>Mass Market Paperback</ns2:Binding>
            <ns2:Brand>Harper</ns2:Brand>
            <ns2:Edition>Reprint</ns2:Edition>
            <ns2:Feature>Great product!</ns2:Feature>
            <ns2:ItemDimensions>
              <ns2:Height Units="inches">1.90</ns2:Height>
              <ns2:Length Units="inches">7.20</ns2:Length>
              <ns2:Width Units="inches">4.20</ns2:Width>
              <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">0.70</ns2:Weight>
            </ns2:ItemDimensions>
            <ns2:Label>Harper</ns2:Label>
            <ns2:Languages>
              <ns2:Language>
                <ns2:Name>english</ns2:Name>
                <ns2:Type>Unknown</ns2:Type>
              </ns2:Language>
              <ns2:Language>
                <ns2:Name>english</ns2:Name>
                <ns2:Type>Original Language</ns2:Type>
              </ns2:Language>
              <ns2:Language>
                <ns2:Name>english</ns2:Name>
                <ns2:Type>Published</ns2:Type>
              </ns2:Language>
            </ns2:Languages>
            <ns2:ListPrice>
              <ns2:Amount>9.99</ns2:Amount>
              <ns2:CurrencyCode>USD</ns2:CurrencyCode>
            </ns2:ListPrice>
            <ns2:Manufacturer>Harper</ns2:Manufacturer>
            <ns2:NumberOfItems>1</ns2:NumberOfItems>
            <ns2:NumberOfPages>576</ns2:NumberOfPages>
            <ns2:PackageDimensions>
              <ns2:Height Units="inches">1.70</ns2:Height>
              <ns2:Length Units="inches">7.40</ns2:Length>
              <ns2:Width Units="inches">4.10</ns2:Width>
              <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">0.70</ns2:Weight>
            </ns2:PackageDimensions>
            <ns2:ProductGroup>Book</ns2:ProductGroup>
            <ns2:ProductTypeName>ABIS_BOOK</ns2:ProductTypeName>
            <ns2:PublicationDate>2014-01-28</ns2:PublicationDate>
            <ns2:Publisher>Harper</ns2:Publisher>
            <ns2:ReleaseDate>2014-01-28</ns2:ReleaseDate>
            <ns2:SmallImage>
              <ns2:URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51evv9CZCOL._SL75_.jpg</ns2:URL>
              <ns2:Height Units="pixels">75</ns2:Height>
              <ns2:Width Units="pixels">42</ns2:Width>
            </ns2:SmallImage>
            <ns2:Studio>Harper</ns2:Studio>
            <ns2:Title>The Eye of God (Sigma Force)</ns2:Title>
          </ns2:ItemAttributes>
        </AttributeSets>
        <Relationships/>
        <SalesRankings>
          <SalesRank>
            <ProductCategoryId>book_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId>
            <Rank>10083</Rank>
          </SalesRank>
        </SalesRankings>
      </Product>
    </Products>
  </GetMatchingProductForIdResult>
  <GetMatchingProductForIdResult Id="NX-USS1-UXRY" IdType="SellerSKU" status="Success">
    <Products>
      <Product>
        <Identifiers>
          <MarketplaceASIN>
            <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
            <ASIN>0375705244</ASIN>
          </MarketplaceASIN>
        </Identifiers>
        <AttributeSets>
          <ns2:ItemAttributes xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd" xml:lang="en-US">
            <ns2:Author>Ellis, Joseph J.</ns2:Author>
            <ns2:Binding>Paperback</ns2:Binding>
            <ns2:Brand>Vintage</ns2:Brand>
            <ns2:Feature>Great product!</ns2:Feature>
            <ns2:ItemDimensions>
              <ns2:Height Units="inches">0.65</ns2:Height>
              <ns2:Length Units="inches">7.84</ns2:Length>
              <ns2:Width Units="inches">5.48</ns2:Width>
              <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">0.51</ns2:Weight>
            </ns2:ItemDimensions>
            <ns2:Label>Vintage</ns2:Label>
            <ns2:Languages>
              <ns2:Language>
                <ns2:Name>english</ns2:Name>
                <ns2:Type>Unknown</ns2:Type>
              </ns2:Language>
              <ns2:Language>
                <ns2:Name>english</ns2:Name>
                <ns2:Type>Original Language</ns2:Type>
              </ns2:Language>
              <ns2:Language>
                <ns2:Name>english</ns2:Name>
                <ns2:Type>Published</ns2:Type>
              </ns2:Language>
            </ns2:Languages>
            <ns2:ListPrice>
              <ns2:Amount>15.95</ns2:Amount>
              <ns2:CurrencyCode>USD</ns2:CurrencyCode>
            </ns2:ListPrice>
            <ns2:Manufacturer>Vintage</ns2:Manufacturer>
            <ns2:NumberOfItems>1</ns2:NumberOfItems>
            <ns2:NumberOfPages>304</ns2:NumberOfPages>
            <ns2:PackageDimensions>
              <ns2:Height Units="inches">1.10</ns2:Height>
              <ns2:Length Units="inches">7.70</ns2:Length>
              <ns2:Width Units="inches">5.10</ns2:Width>
              <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">0.50</ns2:Weight>
            </ns2:PackageDimensions>
            <ns2:PackageQuantity>1</ns2:PackageQuantity>
            <ns2:PartNumber>9780375705243</ns2:PartNumber>
            <ns2:ProductGroup>Book</ns2:ProductGroup>
            <ns2:ProductTypeName>ABIS_BOOK</ns2:ProductTypeName>
            <ns2:PublicationDate>2002-02-05</ns2:PublicationDate>
            <ns2:Publisher>Vintage</ns2:Publisher>
            <ns2:ReleaseDate>2002-02-05</ns2:ReleaseDate>
            <ns2:SmallImage>
              <ns2:URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51KJtm7pCrL._SL75_.jpg</ns2:URL>
              <ns2:Height Units="pixels">75</ns2:Height>
              <ns2:Width Units="pixels">49</ns2:Width>
            </ns2:SmallImage>
            <ns2:Studio>Vintage</ns2:Studio>
            <ns2:Title>Founding Brothers: The Revolutionary Generation</ns2:Title>
          </ns2:ItemAttributes>
        </AttributeSets>
        <Relationships/>
        <SalesRankings>
          <SalesRank>
            <ProductCategoryId>book_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId>
            <Rank>3269</Rank>
          </SalesRank>
          <SalesRank>
            <ProductCategoryId>9681303011</ProductCategoryId>
            <Rank>4</Rank>
          </SalesRank>
          <SalesRank>
            <ProductCategoryId>4871</ProductCategoryId>
            <Rank>7</Rank>
          </SalesRank>
          <SalesRank>
            <ProductCategoryId>11086</ProductCategoryId>
            <Rank>16</Rank>
          </SalesRank>
        </SalesRankings>
      </Product>
    </Products>
  </GetMatchingProductForIdResult>
  <GetMatchingProductForIdResult Id="VB-GNYY-PMZS" IdType="SellerSKU" status="Success">
    <Products>
      <Product>
        <Identifiers>
          <MarketplaceASIN>
            <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
            <ASIN>B00DQAPJSY</ASIN>
          </MarketplaceASIN>
        </Identifiers>
        <AttributeSets>
          <ns2:ItemAttributes xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd" xml:lang="en-US">
            <ns2:Binding>Personal Computers</ns2:Binding>
            <ns2:Brand>JBL</ns2:Brand>
            <ns2:Color>Red</ns2:Color>
            <ns2:Feature>Versatile, portable design</ns2:Feature>
            <ns2:Feature>Five-hour, Li-ion rechargeable battery</ns2:Feature>
            <ns2:Feature>Built-in microphone &amp; call answer button for mobile devices</ns2:Feature>
            <ns2:Label>JBL</ns2:Label>
            <ns2:ListPrice>
              <ns2:Amount>119.95</ns2:Amount>
              <ns2:CurrencyCode>USD</ns2:CurrencyCode>
            </ns2:ListPrice>
            <ns2:Manufacturer>JBL</ns2:Manufacturer>
            <ns2:MediaType>MP3</ns2:MediaType>
            <ns2:Model>JBLFLIPREDAM</ns2:Model>
            <ns2:PackageDimensions>
              <ns2:Height Units="inches">2.90</ns2:Height>
              <ns2:Length Units="inches">7.50</ns2:Length>
              <ns2:Width Units="inches">7.10</ns2:Width>
              <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">1.70</ns2:Weight>
            </ns2:PackageDimensions>
            <ns2:PackageQuantity>1</ns2:PackageQuantity>
            <ns2:PartNumber>JBLFLIPREDAM</ns2:PartNumber>
            <ns2:ProductGroup>Network Media Player</ns2:ProductGroup>
            <ns2:ProductTypeName>PORTABLE_AUDIO</ns2:ProductTypeName>
            <ns2:Publisher>JBL</ns2:Publisher>
            <ns2:SmallImage>
              <ns2:URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/410I6YxfTtL._SL75_.jpg</ns2:URL>
              <ns2:Height Units="pixels">65</ns2:Height>
              <ns2:Width Units="pixels">75</ns2:Width>
            </ns2:SmallImage>
            <ns2:Studio>JBL</ns2:Studio>
            <ns2:Title>JBL Flip Wireless Bluetooth Speaker (Red)</ns2:Title>
          </ns2:ItemAttributes>
        </AttributeSets>
        <Relationships/>
        <SalesRankings>
          <SalesRank>
            <ProductCategoryId>wireless_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId>
            <Rank>17155</Rank>
          </SalesRank>
        </SalesRankings>
      </Product>
    </Products>
  </GetMatchingProductForIdResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>c09070bd-cc9b-485b-9df0-e7ff24b014b5</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</GetMatchingProductForIdResponse>
ResponseHeaderMetadata: RequestId: c09070bd-cc9b-485b-9df0-e7ff24b014b5, ResponseContext: kTgQHamo26t53ZIXhXJTA7jfRyqcib2iqO1Wf/3khcqgfhHFseHa9JYrX8Dlzs9OrGixmPIsCxuZ jSUoBV3RLw==,YR44XTRP1f51djG65oaAWhdNHw0+6V32WmJmZoqkSTeUVHYvq88nOBfaE6EgXq3XTR9WAss6d97r gR/TimYXbQ==, Timestamp: 2014-09-15T05:23:50.364Z, Quota Max: 17772.0, Quota Remaining: 17772.0, Quota Resets At: 2014-09-15T05:25:00.000Z
```

I am trying to get the weight of each item (Product) in the response, which can be found at `GetMatchingProductForIdResult/Products/Product/AttributeSets/ns2:ItemAttributes/ns2:ItemDimensions/ns2:Weight` if you start at the root element of the node. I am trying to use `xpath` like this:

```
$dozy=new DOMDocument();
$dozy->loadXML($response->toXML());

$dozy->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dozy->formatOutput = true;

$xpathy = new DOMXpath($dozy);

$xpathy->registerNamespace('ns2', 'http://www.w3.org/XML/2008/xsdl-exx/ns2');

$weighter = $xpathy->query('//GetMatchingProductForIdResult/Products/Product/AttributeSets/ns2:ItemAttributes/ns2:ItemDimensions/ns2:Weight');
```

However when I go to reference what I got with:

`echo $weighter->item(0)->nodeValue;`

I get an error saying:

`Trying to get property of non-object.`

I think this is happening because `$weighter` is null (it isn't getting anything stored in it) so the `item` function isn't working on it.

Any help for how to target the `ns2:Weight` node would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What went wrong

Your original xpath query fails for a couple reasons:

1.) The namespace you registered for "ns2" is incorrect. The important part is the namespace URI - you can pick whatever you like for the prefix. So:

```
$xpathy->registerNamespace(
    'ns2',
    "http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd"
);
```

2.) Other elements have a default namespace which needs to be registered with a prefix in your DOMXPath object and the prefix used in the expression.

```
$xpathy->registerNamespace(
    'ns',
    "http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01"
);

$weighter = $xpathy->query(
'//ns:GetMatchingProductForIdResult/ns:Products/ns:Product/ns:AttributeSets
/ns2:ItemAttributes/ns2:ItemDimensions/ns2:Weight'
);
```

---

### What *might* be right

Since your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25841721/3942918) indicates that `//*[local-name()="Weight"]'` works fine to select what you're looking for, you can actually skip all the xpath stuff entirely and just use:

```
$weighter = $dozy->getElementsByTagName('Weight');
```

However you'll find both with `getElementsByTagName()` and your abbreviated xpath you're ending up with more elements than you'd have got from a corrected version of your original xpath.

This is because the original was only looking for those at `//ns2:ItemDimensions/ns2:Weight` where the new shortened way also finds those at `//ns2:PackageDimensions/ns2:Weight`.

---

### What might be right*er*

To put stuff altogether to get the results the original would've retrieved you're looking at something like:

```
$dozy=new DOMDocument();
$dozy->loadXML($response->toXML());

$dozy->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dozy->formatOutput = true;

$xpathy = new DOMXpath($dozy);

$xpathy->registerNamespace(
    'ns2',
    "http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd"
);
$xpathy->registerNamespace(
    'ns',
    "http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01"
);

$weighter = $xpathy->query(
    '//ns:GetMatchingProductForIdResult/ns:Products/ns:Product/ns:AttributeSets
    /ns2:ItemAttributes/ns2:ItemDimensions/ns2:Weight'
);

foreach ($weighter as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue, "\n";
}
```

#### Or:

*(A little shorter, but still just as specific for the given sample data.)*

```
$dozy=new DOMDocument();
$dozy->loadXML($response->toXML());

$dozy->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dozy->formatOutput = true;

$xpathy = new DOMXpath($dozy);

$xpathy->registerNamespace(
    'ns2',
    "http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd"
);

$weighter = $xpathy->query(
    '//ns2:ItemDimensions/ns2:Weight'
);

foreach ($weighter as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue, "\n";
}
```

#### Either of which will output:

```
0.60
0.70
0.51
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

`$weighter = $xpathy->query('//*[local-name()="Weight"]');`

Answer (score 0):

`ns2` namespace prefix in your XML declared as follow :

```
<ns2:ItemAttributes 
     xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd" 
     xml:lang="en-US">
```

You need to register corresponding namespace URI :

```
$xpathy->registerNamespace('ns2', 'http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd');
```